# Using RPC or something else

Tags: c++, rpc

Does RPC is still in use nowadays. Or rpc were replaced by other technology?
If i start new project in C++ should i consider use of RPC?

More info because i know that RPC is still in use in production code:

I have two apps to communicate each other. These two are on same machine but one is service, second is user app. User app send to service app every 2,3 seconds. 
Second usage of rpc. I have 1 client and many computers that have local database. And that client need to get some data from these computers.

Should i use something like Thrift for these two scenerios? Or its too big for that?

Comment: That depends on what your new project does.

Comment: I have used D-Bus on a few projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Remote Procedure Call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) is a very generic idea and not something specific. There are [ZeroC Ice](http://zeroc.com/), [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), [Java RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html), [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), [DRb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/drb/rdoc/index.html), [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) and a lot more technologies that are built around the idea of RPC. They are being used indeed. For example, CORBA is used by some [Electronic Currency Exchanges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_communication_network) (ECNs), ZeroC is used by [Skype](http://www.skype.com/), [Hewlett-Packard](http://www.hp.com/), [soap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap) is used... well I hope everyone uses soap.

But it is hard to answer whether you should consider this technology or not. And if you should than what solution you should go with. It depends on too many details. But the main question to ask is — what are you trying to achieve? These are all serious technologies, some can save you tons of valuable time, some can help you integrate applications written in different languages, etc. Basically, every solution has its cons and pros.

If you are certain that you need it, I'd recommend thinking about it twice and decide where in your project you need it and what for. If you decide to go with RPC, I'd recommend you ZeroC Ice. It is free, open source, scalable and extendable, supports tons of modern programming languages and the community around it seems pretty active.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: You wrote that RPC is very generic. Is this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx#base.using_rpc_for_ipc is this same generic concept or something else?

Comment: Your question was tagged only with C++ and rpc.  Given this context, I would interpret it as being "generic"

Comment: @userbb: Concept is generic, implementation is different, and it won't be portable and/or compatible with other solutions (every one of them is not compatible with another).

Comment: ZeroC is not free for commercial, closed-source projects.

Comment: @Emile: Depends what you call closed-source commercial projects. There is a version released under GPL, and you indeed can use it for SAS-kind of projects, or just for internal use in the company.

Answer (score 0):

RPC is widely used in windows operating system. I use RPC to invoke a cache service, for reasons of high performance.

Comment: Just as a note - RPC is not faster than alternative, lower-level solutions. And in most cases is significantly slower.

Comment: It's not true, only direct hardware access can be faster than rpc or shared memory, but the isolation is lost between processes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you do decide you need RPC, I recommend looking at [Apache Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) which supports most common language bindings and has most features you'll ever need.  It might be overkill for your needs, but since you didn't specify them, I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: I have two apps to communicate each other. These two are on same machine but one is service, second is user app. user app send to service every 2,3 seconds. Second usage of rpc. I have 1 client and many computers that have local database. And that client need to get some data from these computers.